# how to build and label a non english dataset for sentiment analysis

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, sentiment-analysis

lately I've started a new project about sentiment analysis and I should build a dataset in Persian language. while building a dataset is important for accuracy of whole process ,I want to do it as good as it's possible in shortest time.
What is the most optimized way to build and label a sentiment analysis dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use available dataset as a reference of yours. There are many sources to get sentiment analysis dataset:

[google](http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html)

[sananalytics](http://www.sananalytics.com/lab/twitter-sentiment/)

[kaggle](http://inclass.kaggle.com/c/si650winter11/data)

[stanford](http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/treebank.html)

Here is a list of datasets that give the sentiments for individual words.

[positivewordsresearch](http://positivewordsresearch.com/sentiment-analysis-resources/)

I suggest to you that work on mentioned datasets in order to increase your knowledge about dataset and their labels.

Generally sentiment datasets uses limited labels such as 
"positive/negative" or 
"happy", "sad", "angry", and "neutral" or
"anger", "sadness", "surprise", "fear", "disgust", and "joy"

Hope to be useful for you.

Comment: the real problem is that it should be in persian.what should I do about that?

Comment: I already got it! It is better to you to have a good background knowledge about related datasets. another suggestion is to create your dataset step by step by review of existing dataset base on your goals. In other word, you should use an existing dataset as a template of your new one in any language. All steps need good knowledge about old language and new one. @kosarafrooshe

Comment: np. @kosarafrooshe